# Make two characters move at the same time

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a little game in the Console App and i want an enemy to move at a constantly while moving the player. The code looks like this right now:

```
public static int y = 5;
    public static string player = "O";
    public static int enemyX = 10;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(enemyX, 10);
            Console.Write("X");
            enemyX = enemyX - 1;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(5, y);
            Console.Write(player);

            var move = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (move.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    y = y - 1;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    y = y + 1;
                    break;
            }
            if (y <= 0)
            {
                y = 1;
            }

            if (y >= 25)
            {
                y = 24;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Console.SetCursorPosition(enemyX, y);`?

Comment: You need to describe exactly what the problem is - what you expect of your code & what you are getting.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I pretty much want the enemy to move towards the player and i wan't the enemy to move freely. As of now the enemy and player moves at the same time when i press W or S. But i want the enemy to move by himself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want the enemy to move regardless of if the player moves or not and to do that you could use [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) 
Example:

```
bool BreakThread = false; //you need this to break the thread loop 
Thread enemyThread = new Thread(()=>
{
  while(!BreakThread)
  {
  //do Enemy Actions
  }
});

enemyThread.Start();
//then execute your main game loop
```

but remember to set the BreakThread value to true when ever you
are closing the game.